# Prove that $1+\sum_{n\geq1}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{n!}{k!}{n-1\choose k-1}x^k\frac{u^n}{n!}=\exp\frac{xu}{1-u}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $k,n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$.  How do I get started to prove that"

$$1+\left(\sum_{n\geq1}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{n!}{k!}{n-1\choose k-1}x^k \frac{u^n}{n!}\right) = \exp\frac{xu}{1-u}$$

Hints and help greatly appreciated!

Comment: How can you fix your running index?

Comment: Ooops, I meant "Let" instead of "Fix", @Danny thanks!

Comment: Is $\mathbb P$ the set of prime numbers?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}$ here stands for positive integers, sorry for being confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this theorem from *Enumerative Combinatorics Volume 2 by R. Stanley*,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{1 + \sum_{n \geq 1}u^{n}
     \bracks{\color{#00f}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k!}{n - 1 \choose k - 1}x^{k}}}
     =\exp\pars{xu \over 1 - u}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k!}{n - 1 \choose k - 1}x^{k}}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k!}\bracks{%
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z^{k}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}x^{k}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1}
> \bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{x/z}^{k} \over k!}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\color{#00f}{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1}\exp\pars{x \over z}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&1 + \sum_{n \geq 1}u^{n}
\bracks{\color{#00f}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k!}{n - 1 \choose k - 1}x^{k}}}
=1 + \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\exp\pars{x/z} \over 1 + z}
\sum_{n \geq 1}\bracks{u\pars{1 + z}}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=1 + \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\exp\pars{x/z} \over 1 + z}
\bracks{{1 \over 1 - u\pars{1 + z}} - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=1 + \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\exp\pars{x/z}\,{u \over 1 - u - uz}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=1  + \color{#f00}{{u \over 1 -u}\,{\rm res}\pars{%
\exp\pars{x \over z}\,{1 \over 1 - uz/\pars{1 - u}}}_{z\ = 0}}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\pars{1}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#f00}{{u \over 1 -u}\,
> {\rm res}\pars{%
> \exp\pars{x \over z}\,{1 \over 1 - uz/\pars{1 - u}}}_{z\ = 0}}
> \\[3mm]&={u \over 1 - u}\,{\rm res}\,\pars{%
> \sum_{\ell = 0}{x^{\ell} \over \ell!}\,{1 \over z^{\ell}}
> \sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}\pars{u \over 1 - u}^{\ell'}z^{\ell'}}_{z\ =\ 0}
> =\sum_{\ell = 1}{1 \over \ell!}\,\pars{{u \over 1 - u}\,x}^{\ell}
> \\[3mm]&=\exp\pars{xu \over 1 - u} - 1
> \end{align}
>   Replace this result in $\pars{1}$ and we arrive to the result.

In order to arrive to the OP result we assumed that
$\ds{\verts{1 - u \over u} > 1}$ such that the only pole is at $\ds{z = 0}$. In addition some intermediate sums require $\ds{\verts{u} < \half}$. I didn't study the compatibility of both conditions. If the OP say something else about $\ds{u}$ I can recheck my answer.