# Applying the Compositional Formula in Enumerative Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Following up on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445045/prove-that-1-sum-n-geq1-sumn-k-1-fracnkn-1-choose-k-1xk-fracun):

I understand the theorem itself, but I'm not sure how to apply the theorem in order to complete the proof.

Can someone provide me some assistance, or hints, to prove that $\forall k,n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$, the following identity holds:

$$1+\left(\sum_{n\geq1}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{n!}{k!}{n-1\choose k-1}x^k \frac{u^n}{n!}\right) = \exp\frac{xu}{1-u}$$

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the theorem I've cited in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445045/prove-that-1-sum-n-geq1-sumn-k-1-fracnkn-1-choose-k-1xk-fracun/445051#445051):

Let $f=n!$, and $g=x^k$, then you should get the identity you desire. Try to think about the identity you mentioned more "combinatorially".